# Smart contracts access count

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Is it possible to know how many times a particular smart contract is accessed as in the count, for various purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use etherscan once you deploy your contract to check all the transactions. The transaction count will likely be the number of access received by the contract.

example [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819) has about [9232058](https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819) transactions. If you want something more specific you need to develop it.